# Concurrent Session-Independent Java Web App?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, daemon, listeners

Is it possible to deploy an application to a GlassFish app server that would behave more like a daemon than a web app? I'd like to set up some sort of daemon app that would relay requests to an API that only allows for one connection at a time.

This way I could have multiple servlet instances that could simply submit API requests through the daemon and avoid ever needing more than one connection to the API.

I'm fairly new to Java-based web apps, so I'm not entirely certain what to search for, or if this kind of functionality is available in, say, the Java-EE development kit. Any help appreciated!

Updates/Ideas:

- **Lifecycle Module:** What about building the daemon as a lifecycle module? From what I gather, I could effectively manage its behavior based on the app server's status, which could actually be beneficial in my case: http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3672/beamc?l=en&a=view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GlassFish v3 supports EJB 3.1 Singleton Beans:

A Singleton Bean could be used to implement the requirement "relay requests to an API that only allows for one connection at a time".

> By default, all Singleton methods are
>   made thread-safe and transactional.
>   This means that all multithreaded
>   access to the bean is serialized (...)

(from [New Features in EJB 3.1 - theserverside.com](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363656/New-Features-in-EJB-31))

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a servlet that feeds a message queue. Then you can have some code that pulls entries off the queue and processes them. Look up Message-Driven Beans.